# How to select by time?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

How to select songs (id) which are more than 2:00:00 length, using TIME_TO_SEC()?

```
songs
id  length
8   02:06:04
1   00:09:08
2   05:38:32
4   01:22:25
4   01:18:53
2   01:45:08
5   00:26:19
```

output

```
 id time
 2   7:23:40
 8    2:06:04
 4   2:41:18
```

Comment: Hint:  `where time_to_sec(length) > 2*60*60`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, thanks. Can I use where (select SEC_TO_TIME(sum(IFNULL(TIME_TO_SEC(length ), 0)))) > 2:00:00);

Comment: USE COALESCE function for that

Comment: `NULL` values will fail the condition, so there is no reason to treat them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work properly:

```
SELECT id, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(length))) AS time
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(length)) >  2 * 60 * 60
```

Answer (score 2):

use simple `where` clause with  7200 sec

```
select * from songs where TIME_TO_SEC(length)>7200
```

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков if you directly want to use 2:00:00 then you can follow tim solution

Comment: but I need first convert to seconds separately?

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков then change your question what you want, its tough to understand because you describe one thing in question but said in comment different things you want, then how can read your mind ,please describe properly with sample output what you want

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to use `TIME_TO_SEC` here.  We can do a direct comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM songs
WHERE length > '02:00:00';
```

This assumes that either your `length` column is a bona fide time column, or it is text but with all data having the same width of 8 (6 digits).

The advantage of this approach is that it allows an index on `length` to be used in the query.

Comment: thanks, does your query summarize time when id is the same?

Comment: That sounds like a new question.  Maybe you should edit your question and tell us the real requirements.

Comment: I voted to close as being unclear.  I have no idea what you actually want here.